# JMXterm command works manually from terminal but not from script, what could be the reason?

Tags: jmx

I'm trying to automate a JMX command using a tool called JMXterm.

The script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
beanstemp="/tmp/jmx_beans"
read -r -p "Enter server name in FQDN " scrapername
bean1="BrokerName=localhost,Connection=Scraper_$scrapername,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection"
echo beans -d $domain | $cmd  > $beanstemp
idnum=$(grep "ID_$scrapername" $beanstemp | grep openwire | awk -F- '{print $2"-"$3}')
idname="$scrapername-$idnum"
bean2="BrokerName=localhost,Connection=ID_"$idname"2_0,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection"
domain="org.apache.activemq"
server="scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099"
cmd="java -jar Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l $server"

echo run stop -b $bean1 -d $domain | $cmd -l $server
echo run stop -b $bean2 -d $domain | $cmd -l $server
```

When I run the script I get the proper response for the first command but the second one fails.

Here's the output of `sh -x`:

```
itaig@iganot-lt:~$ sh -x jmx.sh 
+ beanstemp=/tmp/jmx_beans
+ read -r -p Enter server name in FQDN  scrapername
Enter server name in FQDN selvmnj27.domain.company.com
+ bean1=BrokerName=localhost,Connection=Scraper_selvmnj27.domain.company.com,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection
+ echo beans -d
+ 
+ + grep openwire
grep ID_selvmnj27.domain.company.com+ awk -F- {print $2"-"$3}
 /tmp/jmx_beans
+ idnum=
+ idname=selvmnj27.domain.company.com-
+ bean2=BrokerName=localhost,Connection=ID_selvmnj27.domain.company.com-2_0,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection
+ domain=org.apache.activemq
+ server=scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099
+ cmd=java -jar Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099
+ echo+  run stop -b BrokerName=localhost,Connection=Scraper_selvmnj27.domain.company.com,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connectionjava -jar -d Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l org.apache.activemq scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099 -l
 scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
$>run stop -b BrokerName=localhost,Connection=Scraper_selvmnj27.domain.company.com,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection -d org.apache.activemq
#calling operation stop of mbean org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Connection=Scraper_selvmnj27.domain.company.com,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection
#operation returns: 
null
$>+ + echo runjava stop -b -jar Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar BrokerName=localhost,Connection=ID_selvmnj27.domain.company.com-2_0,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection -l scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099 -l -d scrapermq.sj.peer39.com:1099
 org.apache.activemq
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
$>run stop -b BrokerName=localhost,Connection=ID_selvmnj27.domain.company.com-2_0,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection -d org.apache.activemq
#InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Connection=ID_selvmnj27.domain.company.com-2_0,ConnectorName=openwire,Type=Connection
$>itaig@iganot-lt:~$
```

"Operation returns: null" is the response I'm looking for.

The problem begins with this line:

```
echo beans -d $domain | $cmd  > $beanstemp
```

When it runs the output of the command should be written to the $beanstemp file but the file stays empty.

When I run the command manually from terminal it works:

```
itaig@iganot-lt:~$ echo beans -d org.apache.activemq | java -jar Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar  -l  scrapermq.domain.company.com:1099 > /tmp/jmx_beans
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
$>beans -d org.apache.activemq
#domain = org.apache.activemq:
$>itaig@iganot-lt:~$ tail -5 /tmp/jmx_beans
org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Subscription,clientId=Scraper_selvmnj28.domain.company.com,consumerId=ID_selvmnj28.domain.company.com-45117-1431866382308-0_416_1_1,destinationName=SCRAPER_VIDEO_INPUT,destinationType=Queue,persistentMode=Non-Durable
org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Subscription,clientId=Scraper_selvmnj29.domain.company.com,consumerId=ID_selvmnj29.domain.company.com-52961-1431866382264-0_416_-1_1,destinationName=topic_//ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue_topic_//ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic,destinationType=Topic,persistentMode=Non-Durable
org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Subscription,clientId=Scraper_selvmnj29.domain.company.com,consumerId=ID_selvmnj29.domain.company.com-52961-1431866382264-0_416_1_1,destinationName=SCRAPER_VIDEO_INPUT,destinationType=Queue,persistentMode=Non-Durable
org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Subscription,clientId=Scraper_selvmnj30.domain.company.com,consumerId=ID_selvmnj30.domain.company.com-33036-1431866396456-0_416_-1_1,destinationName=topic_//ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue_topic_//ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic,destinationType=Topic,persistentMode=Non-Durable
org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Subscription,clientId=Scraper_selvmnj30.domain.company.com,consumerId=ID_selvmnj30.domain.company.com-33036-1431866396456-0_416_1_1,destinationName=SCRAPER_VIDEO_INPUT,destinationType=Queue,persistentMode=Non-Durable
itaig@iganot-lt:~$
```

So my question is: What am I doing wrong and why does the command work when running manually from terminal but not from the script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.

Certain lines included variables which have not been declared in time.
After re-organizing the order of variable declaration the problem has been solved.